# canvas preview is not proper in jcrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jcrop

I am stuck in jcrop canvas preview functionality 
when I am trying to crop image then canvas preview shows stretch image :(
And I dont want to use **aspectRatio: 1,**

Here my code

```
  $(function(){
      $('#target').Jcrop({
          onChange: updatePreview,
      })
  })

  function updatePreview(c) {
    if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
      var imageObj = jQuery("#target")[0];
      var canvas = jQuery("#preview")[0];
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.drawImage(imageObj, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, 300, 150);
    }
  };
```

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NG4eu/21/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the aspect ratio of 1, then adjust to your desired aspect ratio... then adjust the style height and width of the canvas to meet the new aspect ratio

Comment: Thanks, @Luks Arnold but I want free selection